# SIGUSR2 error: Loading rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, terminal

I tried to start my rails server and the localhost/3000 does not open.

This is what shows in my browser :- [Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyzBk.png)

And this is what appears on my terminal :- [Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcdOn.png)

Comment: I could not add the images to this question post. Click on the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use localhost:3000 and not localhost/3000.

Comment: Oh yes! Im sorry. Didnt see that